# Django Storages using s3boto ignoring MEDIA_URL

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-storage, django-media

I am trying to use django-storages with s3boto in my app and trying to serve media and static files from s3.

I have the following settings in my settings file:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '<bucket_name>'
AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '<access_key>'
AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '<secret>'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = '<custom_storage_satic>'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = '<custom_storage_media>'
```

And my custom_storages.py is

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

When I create an image in django, instead of getting the relative path to my image starting with

```
image.url
'/media/image/<rest_of_the_path>.jpg'
```

I am getting the absolute url, which is something like

```
image.url
'https://<s3_bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com/media/image/original/'
```

When I use local storage instead of s3boto, it works as expected and gives me the relative path. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I struck the same issue when attempting to use the Imgix CDN for my S3 media (I suspect we're both using the [same tutorial](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/) based on your use of the `custom_storages.py` override).

Here is an abridged version of the [S3BotoStorage](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/s3boto.py) class in the django-storages framework. This excerpt highlights the important properties and methods for this issue, namely the `custom-domain` property.

```
class S3BotoStorage(Storage):
    location = setting('AWS_LOCATION', '')
    custom_domain = setting('AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN')

    def url(self, name, headers=None, response_headers=None, expire=None):
        # Preserve the trailing slash after normalizing the path.
        name = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(name))
        if self.custom_domain:
            return "%s//%s/%s" % (self.url_protocol, self.custom_domain, filepath_to_uri(name))
```

As you can see in the `url` method, a URL is generated to override the `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL` Django settings. Currently the domain of the URL is created with the `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` setting, which is why you continue to see the static S3 URL for media files.

So first, in your Django settings file, add a setting describing your CDN's domain.

```
IMGIX_DOMAIN = 'example.imgix.net'
```

Then, similar to the override of the `location` property, add an override to the `custom_domain` property in your `MediaStorage` class.

```
class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
    custom_domain = settings.IMGIX_DOMAIN
```

Now the final URL to your media files should begin with your CDN's domain, followed by the relative path to your file on the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving static media from an S3 bucket, you *must* use an absolute URL, since the media is being served from a wholly different server.

Comment: But what if I wanted to switch my s3 bucket, or if I wanted to use a CDN. Conceptually is there any reason to not store your media url from /media even if you are serving from a while different server?