# Custom S3Boto3Storage with django-storages

Tags: django, amazon-s3, minio, python-django-storages

I developed a Django app that I'm using VM's disk for saving and serving media and static files but in one of my models, I want to save my files in a FileField connected to my MinIO object storage. I set up the settings like this in the `settings.py`

```py
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '###'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '###'
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = '###'
```

and in my model I used S3Storage like this:

```py
class CustomStorageBucket(S3Boto3Storage):
    bucket_name = "files"

class Document(BaseModel):
    document_file = models.ImageField(storage=CustomStorageBucket(),upload_to='documents')
```

with these codes, I can save my files into the storage but the URLs in the admin panel do not works properly because it points to the media files URL something like this :

```
http://localhost:8000/media/documents/file.jpg
```

but I want it to be like this ( presigned URL) :

```
https://object-storage.app/files/documents/file.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXX&X-Amz-Date=XXX&X-Amz-Expires=432000&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=XXX
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to set [MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#media-url) variable

```
MEDIA_URL = 'https://object-storage.app/files/'
```

Comment: I can not use it because I have some other files in the media and static directories

Comment: @OmidRoshani maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38276944/8153147) helps you